# Window load event doesn't fire when the page is loaded via link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am attempting to run some javascript when the page is loaded. The issue is that when the page is loaded via a link the `$(window).load(function()` does not fire. If I load the page directly it does work as expected. How can I fix this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you meaning to use document.ready instead?

Comment: `$(window).load(function()` is to load content in via ajax, it is not an event. use `$(document).ready(function()` instead

Comment: @RoryPicko92 not entirely correct. .load as an event binding method is depreciated though as of 1.8

Comment: This event should fire regardless of how you get to the page, as long as it's a page reload. If you load it in via ajax, it of course won't fire because the window didn't reload.

Comment: The same thing happens when I use `$(document).ready(function()` The event never fires. When the page is loaded via link.

Comment: That's because the window isn't reloading. All you're doing is ajax loading in content. You should be using pageinit instead.

Comment: what do you mean by not firing? events attached? to attached events to dynamically loaded item `$(document).on('event', '.selector', function ()`

Comment: @Omar I mean my code that is located in the `$(window).load(function() {    });` block is not running

@KevinB `$(document).on('pageinit','#CloseCall', function(){ });` is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not causing the `window` to reload when you click on the link — likely due to an asynchronous call. If you want to kick off a bit of code when the link is `click`ed you'll need to handle the `click` event.

```
$('a#someLinkId').on('click', function(){

});
```

---

Or, as stated by @KevinB, executing you're code on the *successful* completion of an AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "someserverresource.html"
}).done(function() {
    yourClientSideLogic();
});
```

Comment: or the success of said ajax call

Comment: @KevinB right, the success of the ajax call would, most likely, be a better alternative.

Comment: What would the code on the success of the ajax call look like. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt Are you making the ajax call, or is jQM doing it for you. I suspect jQM is making the ajax call, in which case the success callback would be harder to use than simply using the pageinit event.

Comment: depends on what you're using to make the AJAX call, which you haven't provided.